# How to negate default IGNORECASE by string modifier in python re

Tags: python, regex

I have a script that searches through a text file for lines that match a regex passed in as a command line argument.

By default the scripts does a case insensitive search (I want it this way).

How do i pass in the -i flag in the regex argument to force a case sensitive search. I have tried the below but could not figure it out.

It always performs a case insensitive search.

I have tried this on both python 2.7 and 3.6.

```
>>> import re
>>> res1 = 'TEST'
>>> res2 = 'test'
>>> res3 = '(?-i:)TEST'
>>> res4 = '(?-i:)TeSt'
>>> res5 = '((?-i:)TeSt)'
>>>
>>> string = 'TeSt'
>>>
>>> def str_match(re_str = ''):
...     print(re.search(r'(?i)' + re_str, string))
...
>>>
>>> str_match(res1)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='TeSt'>
>>>
>>> str_match(res2)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='TeSt'>
>>>
>>> str_match(res3)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='TeSt'>
>>>
>>> str_match(res4)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='TeSt'>
>>>
>>> str_match(res5)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='TeSt'>
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> def str_match_2(re_str = ''):
...     print(re.search(re_str, string, re.I))
...
>>>
>>> str_match_2(res1)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='TeSt'>
>>>
>>> str_match_2(res2)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='TeSt'>
>>>
>>> str_match_2(res3)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='TeSt'>
>>>
>>> str_match_2(res4)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='TeSt'>
>>>
>>> str_match_2(res5)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='TeSt'>
>>>
>>> str_match('none')
None
>>>
>>> str_match_2('none')
None
```

Comment: @heemayl Yes, Agreed. But i want the function/script to be cases insensitive by default and the user to pass in the -i flag to force a case sensitive search if needed in rare cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Should have read the documentation more carefully.

Need to format the regex like this:

```
res5 = '(?-i:TeSt)'
```